# Ajax error using JQuery 2.0.3 on mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have written a mobile HTML5 website using standard jQuery. 
I have an ajax request that seem to not be executed.

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){

    //this appears
    $(".fa-plane").after("<p class='error'>"+"clic submit"+"</p>");

    // Make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: '/submit/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#form").serializeArray(),
        success: function (data) {

            //doesnt appear, nothing logged server side
            $(".fa-plane").after("<p class='error'>"+"ajax returning : "+data+"</p>");

        }
    });
});
```

Sometimes it submits, sometimes not (same phone, same url)

nothing logged serverside, success callback not executed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the output? Have you checked firebug/developer tools to see if the request is failing? Could you be unbinding the click event at all?

Comment: The error only happens on mobile, how could I get JS console ?
Inside the listener, the code is executed, but no callback and no log serverside.